# JavaFX JDK 9.0.4 ListView celFactory adds null cells

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-9

Why does the CellFactory add so many null elements in this list? I explicitly set
an observable array with just "a" and "b"
I don't think it's a problem with the bindings ... 
Any suggestions?

```
package at.kingcastle.misc;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainSpielwiese  extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<String> lv = new ListView<>();
        lv.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new String[] {"a", "b"}));

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(lv);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        lv.setCellFactory(list -> {
            ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<>();
            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            cell.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%s", cell.itemProperty()));
            return cell;
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty cells always have `null` as their `item`.

A string format will format `null` as the literal string `"null"` (the string containing the four characters `n`, `u`, `l`, and `l`). Consequently, your binding will display the text `"null"` in all the empty cells.

Since you have string data in this column, you can just do

```
cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());
```

which will set the text to the *value* `null` instead of the literal string `"null"` when the cell is empty.

More generally (i.e. for data types that are not `String`, so you can't use the binding above), you can do something like

```
cell.textProperty().bind(Bindings.
    when(cell.emptyProperty()).
    then("").
    otherwise(Bindings.format("%s", cell.itemProperty())));
```

or

```
cell.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    if (cell.isEmpty()) {
        return "" ;
    } else {
        return String.format("%s", cell.getItem());
    }
}, cell.itemProperty(), cell.emptyProperty());
```

or

```
cell.textProperty().bind(new StringBinding() {
    {
        bind(cell.textProperty(), cell.emptyProperty());
    }
    @Override
    public String computeValue() {
        return cell.isEmpty() ? "" : String.format("%s", cell.getItem()) ;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @PhilippKönig See also the [documentation for Cell.updateItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem-T-boolean-).